# Convert uint8 byte array to any WPF rendering object

Tags: c#, c++, bitmap, clr, wrapper

currently I have built wrapper for c# using C++ CLR. C++ clr class gets frames from video camera as uint8[] and returns to OnVideoFrame event inside c++ class. I have initializer like this:

```
ZeroMemory(&bmi_, sizeof(bmi_));
bmi_.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi_.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi_.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmi_.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmi_.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmi_.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
bmi_.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width * height * (bmi_.bmiHeader.biBitCount >> 3);
image_.reset(new uint8[bmi_.bmiHeader.biSizeImage]);
```

So the question would be:

I already have data in image_ , but how to send that data to c# and convert it to any WPF bitmap object to play my local video stream? I am looking for best way regarding performance and the problem I have that I am using WPF. I already have a solution for basic win32 app:

```
RECT rcClient;
GetClientRect(VideoRendererInternal->WindowHandle, &rcClient);
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(VideoRendererInternal->WindowHandle, &ps);
StretchDIBits(hdc,
    0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom,  // destination rect
    0, 0, VideoRendererInternal->bmi_.bmiHeader.biWidth, -VideoRendererInternal->bmi_.bmiHeader.biHeight,  // source rect
    VideoRendererInternal->image_.get(), &VideoRendererInternal->bmi_, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
EndPaint(VideoRendererInternal->WindowHandle, &ps);
```

But can't find any solution for WPF. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, I would suggest you have a look at https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-82 where they do exactly that. Here is another solution to display an image from c++ using WPF.

Using MVVM, you need a Image in XAML which you can set with any bitmap source. On doing so WPF would redraw the image. This is highly optimised under the hood (tested at 4k @ 60fps).

```
<Image x:Name="MainFrameBitmap" 
Height="{Binding ImageProcessingModel.MainFrameBitmap.Height}" 
Width="{Binding ImageProcessingModel.MainFrameBitmap.Width}" 
Source="{Binding ImageProcessingModel.MainFrameBitmap, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Cursor="Cross" >
```

In your ImageProcessingModel you might want to get bytes from a c++ land using pinvoke or over a pipe. A timer here is useful as you do not want to block the UI from doing its thing. WPF has the capability to natively render at 120fps, so this can be helpful if the frame source is not periodic or running at a slow frame rate.

```
public class ImageProcessingModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BitmapSource MainFrameBitmap
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainFrameBitmap;
        }
        private set
        {
            _mainFrameBitmap = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainFrameBitmap");
        }
    }

    public ImageProcessingModel(int updatePeriodInMilliseconds)
    {
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += ServiceUiDispatcherTimerTick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, updatePeriodInMilliseconds);
    }


    private void ServiceUiDispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MainFrameBitmap = ReadBitmap(FrameWidth, FrameHeight, Stride);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"UI Runtime Exception:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

You might like to have another class to keep track of these raw image bytes

```
byte[] _imageData
public BitmapSource ReadBitmap(int w, int h, int s )
{
    int size = w*h*3 + 54;

    _imageData = new byte[size];

    // Read from pipe Read(_temp, 0, size);
    // Or use PInvoke to get a reference and manage that

    return BitmapSource.Create(w, h, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, _imageData, s);
}
```

Over in c++ land you need to construct your bytes for any given frame, this would depend on the framework you are using. The example below is using OpenCV but the code would be similar if using RGBQUAD or some such byte buffer to store the image. The image format (and memory alignment) selected here would need to match up with the BitmapSource.Create function in your WPF app.

```
std::vector<uchar> buffer
DWORD UIConnection::writeToPipe(cv::Mat inputFrame){

    int buffSize = (inputFrame.rows * inputFrame.cols * 3) + 54;

    cv::Mat serviceImage;
    inputFrame.copyTo(serviceImage);

    flip(serviceImage, serviceImage, 1);
    imencode(".bmp", serviceImage, buffer);
    reverse(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());

    WriteFile(hPipe, &buffer[0], buffSize * sizeof(uchar), bytesWritten, NULL);

    return *bytesWritten;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for a quick reply! Solved by using half of your answer. Didn't like the timer, so just made a delegate from c++ to send IntPtr:

```
public delegate void OnNewFrame(IntPtr bitmapBuffer, int bitmapBufferLength);
...
public:
event OnNewFrame ^OnNewFrameEvent;`
```

and then:

```
System::IntPtr buffer = System::IntPtr(VideoRendererInternal->image_.get());    
OnNewFrameEvent(buffer, bufferSize);
```

On the C# side:

```
...
renderer.OnNewFrameEvent += new OnNewFrame(OnNewVideoFrame);
}

private void OnNewVideoFrame(IntPtr bitmapBuffer, int bitmapBufferLength)
{
    FrameDispatcher.Instance.DispatchFrame("LocalVideo", bitmapBuffer, bitmapBufferLength);
}
```

Frame dispatcher class:

```
class FrameDispatcher
{

    private static FrameDispatcher StaticInstance;
    private Dictionary<String, FrameRenderer> Renderers = new Dictionary<string, FrameRenderer>();

    public static FrameDispatcher Instance {

        get {

            if (StaticInstance == null)
            {
                StaticInstance = new FrameDispatcher();
            }

            return StaticInstance;

        }

    }

    public void DispatchFrame(String id, IntPtr bitmapBuffer, int bitmapBufferLength)
    {

        if (Renderers.ContainsKey(id))
        {

            BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(640, 480, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null, bitmapBuffer, bitmapBufferLength, 640 * 8);                
            Renderers[id].SetBitmap(bitmap);                

        }

    }

    public void RegisterFrameRenderer(FrameRenderer renderer, String id)
    {
        Renderers.Add(id, renderer);
    }

    public void UnregisterFrameRenderer(String id)
    {
        Renderers.Remove(id);
    }

}
```

Frame renderer class:

```
   class FrameRenderer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private BitmapSource _Bitmap;

    public BitmapSource Bitmap
    {
        get
        {
            return _Bitmap;
        }

        private set
        {
            _Bitmap = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Bitmap");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {               
            try
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"UI Runtime Exception:" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }

    public void SetBitmap(BitmapSource bitmap) {

        bitmap.Freeze();
        Bitmap = bitmap;
        GC.Collect();

    }

}
```

And registering FrameRenderer in MainWindow controller:

```
Renderer = new FrameRenderer();
FrameDispatcher.Instance.RegisterFrameRenderer(Renderer, "LocalVideo");

DataContext = Renderer;
```

And now it works, thanks again :)